# Create PostScript file from vim

Tags: command-line, vim, syntax-highlighting

How can I open a script file and automatic create the PostScript file?
Now I use:

```
vim file.py
```

and inside `:ha > text.ps`.

The problem is that the command have to go inside a bash script. How can I automatize this in one-line code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
vim -c "ha > text.ps | q" file.py
```

`-c` is used to run commands after the file has been opened.

Comment: Woow I didn't know the -c command